# Why do i get a NumberFormatException

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer f = null;
    try {
        f = Integer.valueOf("12.3"); 
        String s = f.toString(); 
        int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
        System.out.println("i = " + i);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("trouble : " + f + e);
    } 
}
```

Comment: because an `Integer` is not a floating number, hence `12.3` isn´t valid.

Comment: Is 12.3 an Integer?  If not then `valueOf` Throws:
NumberFormatException - if the string cannot be parsed as an integer.

Comment: You should use `Flaot.parseFloat` instead of `Integer`. `12.3` isn't an integer.

Comment: An improper of edit of this Question was made changing `Integer` to `Float`. I rolled back that bad edit as it completely changes the nature of the Question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is when you call `"Integer.parseInt(s)"`, the method believe you have integer content in there and it will convert the `string` into the `int`. But now you have float value there. So it cannot convert into integer from string(that contain floating point value) by `Integer.parseInt()` method.  What you can do is

```
 float fl = Float.parseFloat(s);

 int i = (int) f1;
```

Comment: Beware of the [inherent inaccuracy of floating-point types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems) such as `float`. Consider [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

### Here Actual Error is:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "12.3"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:582)
    at Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

### Root cause from java-doc:

```
/**
 * Factory method for making a <code>NumberFormatException</code>
 * given the specified input which caused the error.
 *
 * @param   s   the input causing the error
 */
static NumberFormatException forInputString(String s) {
    return new NumberFormatException("For input string: \"" + s + "\"");
}
```

### Why it happens and how to ommit?

> Thrown to indicate that the application has attempted to convert    a
>   string to one of the numeric types, but that the string does not
>   have the appropriate format.

So change your 12.3 value to 12. As it is already commented by [Kevin Esche](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1799530/kevin-esche) and [scary-wombat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2310289/scary-wombat)

Answer (score 0):

## Not an integer

An integer is a whole number such as 12 or 13. Your 12.3 is a fractional number, not an integer. So it cannot be parsed by the `Integer` class.

## `BigDecimal`

Instead you should parse with the [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class.

```
BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal( "12.3" );
```

## Float

If you want speed rather that accuracy, use the `float` or `double` primitive types.

The [floating-point](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) types can [introduce extraneous digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems) in the decimal fraction. So when accuracy matters such as with currency/money amounts, stick with `BigDecimal`. As the [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) says:

> float … should never be used for precise values, such as currency. For that, you will need to use the java.math.BigDecimal class instead.

```
float f = Float.parseFloat( "12.3" );
```

If you want a float but as an object rather than a [primitive](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) `float`, construct a [`Float`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html).

```
Float f = new Float( "12.3" );
```

Comment: He should parse with `Float`.

Comment: @xenteros It depends on context. If doing calculations for a game a `float` may be appropriate. If handling money, a `float` is *not* appropriate. The Question does not specify the context.

Comment: Dear Down-Voter, please leave a critique along with your vote. And if you simply do not understand the nature of floating-point technology and the advantage of `BigDecimal` please do some study before voting.